# Op-amp LED project

Tags: operational-amplifier, transistors, led, npn

I'm trying to understand this circuit, but I'm having trouble understanding what the second op-amp block does.

I understand tha the first one is an oscillator controlled by a trimpot (RL,) but the second one I couldn't understand very well.

I understand that the current in the transistor has to be very large, given the amount of LEDs at the output of the circuit, so would U1 be playing the role of current buffer? Could someone explain to me how this circuit works as soon as the signal leaves the first op-amp?

Recommendations are welcome to improve the project.

[image]

Comment: You have drawn the circuit in a circuit simulator. Have you tried to simulate the circuit how it works?

Answer (score 1):

The first op amp is configured as a non-inverting schmitt trigger, the second op amp is configured as an integrator. Put together like that, they form an oscillator with a triangle wave output and so the output of the second op amp ramps up and down to give the LEDs a "breathing effect" (slowly illuminating and then slowly dimming).

The transistor is in emitter follower mode and so boosts the current.

An improvement would be to use a resistor with each LED rather than having the LEDs all sharing one resistor. It is risking burning out some of the LEDs by using one shared resistor. The resistors would have to be sized appropriately.